# Need help on how to convert XML file to CSV with C#

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I'm trying to convert an xml file into a csv file with C# but, I'm not having any luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here is my XML file and below is my current code. I'm also getting some errors such as
"Feature 'top-level statements' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater"
"Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations"
"A new expression requires an argument list or (), [], {} after type"

```
<XML>
    <XMLMsgsRs>
        <GeneralSummaryReportQueryRs requestID="1" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
            <ReportRet>
                <ReportTitle>Physical Inventory Worksheet</ReportTitle>
                <ReportSubtitle>All Transactions</ReportSubtitle>
                <ReportBasis>Accrual</ReportBasis>
                <NumRows>2793</NumRows>
                <NumColumns>6</NumColumns>
                <NumColTitleRows>1</NumColTitleRows>
                <ColDesc colID="1" dataType="STRTYPE">
                    <ColTitle titleRow="1" />
                    <ColType>Blank</ColType>
                </ColDesc>
                <ColDesc colID="2" dataType="STRTYPE">
                    <ColTitle titleRow="1" value="Item Description" />
                    <ColType>ItemDesc</ColType>
                </ColDesc>
                <ColDesc colID="3" dataType="STRTYPE">
                    <ColTitle titleRow="1" value="Pref Vendor" />
                    <ColType>ItemVendor</ColType>
                </ColDesc>
                <ColDesc colID="4" dataType="QUANTYPE">
                    <ColTitle titleRow="1" value="On Hand" />
                    <ColType>QuantityOnHand</ColType>
                </ColDesc>
                <ColDesc colID="5" dataType="STRTYPE">
                    <ColTitle titleRow="1" value="U/M" />
                    <ColType>UnitOfMeasureUnit</ColType>
                </ColDesc>
                <ColDesc colID="6" dataType="INTTYPE">
                    <ColTitle titleRow="1" value="Physical Count" />
                    <ColType>PhysicalCount</ColType>
                </ColDesc>
                <ReportData>
                    <TextRow rowNumber="1" value="Inventory" />
                    <TextRow rowNumber="2" value="05-16 TRD  FRONT SEAT COVERS" />
                    <DataRow rowNumber="3">
                        <RowData rowType="item" value="05-16 TRD  FRONT SEAT COVERS:TRAC0506FPBB" />
                        <ColData colID="1" value="TRAC0506FPBB (BARTACT TOYOTA  TRD  2005-06 FRONT SEAT COVERS BLACK - BLACK)" />
                        <ColData colID="2" value="BARTACT TOYOTA  TRD  2005-06 FRONT SEAT COVERS BLACK - BLACK" />
                        <ColData colID="3" value="AR Square INC" />
                        <ColData colID="4" value="-7" />
                        <ColData colID="5" value="pr" />
                    </DataRow>
                    <DataRow rowNumber="4">
                        <RowData rowType="item" value="05-16 TRD  FRONT SEAT COVERS:TRAC0506FPBC" />
                        <ColData colID="1" value="TRAC0506FPBC (BARTACT TOYOTA  TRD  2005-06 FRONT SEAT COVERS BLACK - COYOTE)" />
                        <ColData colID="2" value="BARTACT TOYOTA  TRD  2005-06FRONT SEAT COVERS BLACK - COYOTE" />
                        <ColData colID="3" value="AR Square INC" />
                        <ColData colID="4" value="0" />
                        <ColData colID="5" value="pr" />
                    </DataRow>
              </ReportData>
           </ReportRet>
        </GeneralSummaryReportQueryRs>
    </XMLMsgsRs>
</XML>
```

Here is my current code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class ReportData
{
    public DataRow [] SourcePath { get; set; }
}

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\inventory.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ReportRet[]));
    var data = (ReportRet[])serializer.Deserialize(fs);
    List<string> list = new List<string>;
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        List<string> ss = new List<string>();
        foreach (var point in item.SourcePath) ss.Add(DataRow.ColData + "," + DataRow.ColData);
        list.Add(string.Join(",", ss));

    }

    File.WriteAllLines("C:\\csvFile.csv", list);
}
```

Comment: its not clear what exactly are you expecting from your result, can you give an example?

Comment: and Type ReportRet is missing too

Comment: regarding the Top Level Domain, it happens because you are writing logic not inside a function,
this feature is supported from C# 9, you can use higher version of C# nad that warning would dissapear

Comment: Where did you get this XML from-it's incomplete. There are open tags for `ReportRet` and `ReportData`, but no closing tags. Also, `xml` has special meaning in an XML file, and shouldn't be used as a tag as it can lead to confusion. `TextRow` seems to have a similar format to `DataRow`, so it's unclear if this is intentional, or if it's a mistake.

Comment: The xml file has thousands of fields so I cut it intentionally. But I can fix that and update the XML

Comment: I want to covert this inventory xml report, to a CSV file report. I'm pretty new to all this, and I'm learning as I go so I apologize for my ignorance